# Concourse pipeline build fails with error hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote

Tags: git, bitbucket, concourse-git-resource, concourse-pipeline

Concourse pipeline build fails with error hint:

```
Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
demo_app-source
Updated tag 'DEMO_0.0.3' (was fb544ad)
To https://proactionus..com/bitbucket/scm/cacsad/demo.git
 ! [rejected]        DEMO_0.0.3 -> DEMO_0.0.3 (already exists)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://proactionus.com/bitbucket/scm/cacsad/demo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
```

How can I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your scenario:

- either you see that error on a loop (see "[issue 265: Ability to specify maximum number of retries?](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource/issues/265)")
- or you have somehow move/reapply an existing tag to a different commit, as described in [issue 129](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource/issues/129)

In the second case, make sure to restore the `DEMO_0.0.3` to its original place (check where it is in the remote `origin`)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by running below command from git bash under repository path
git tag -l | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, but in my scenario the branch name was the same as a tag. You are not allowed to give a branch and a tag the same name.